# How to perform two animations at a time on imageview?

Tags: android, xml, animation

I am trying to perform an animation is shaking the imageview and moving the same imageview from left to right at time.I have written my anim xml files are:

**shake_move.xml:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:duration="1500"
            android:fromYDelta="0"
            android:interpolator="@anim/cycle"
            android:toYDelta="15">
   <set>
    <translate
        android:duration="2500"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="100%p" />
    </set> 

</translate>
```

**cycle.xml:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <cycleInterpolator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
                    android:cycles="4"
  />
```

by using above xml file I have implemented as follows:

```
  Animation shakMoveAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MoveAnimImage.this, R.anim.shake_move);
  ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).startAnimation(shakMoveAnim);
```

From the above implementation i am getting only one animation is moving image view from left to right but not shaking the imageview at the same time.

Please help me on perform the both shake and move image view at the same time

Answer (score 0):

[Animation Set](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationSet.html)

User this. Add few animations to AnimationSet.

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shareInterpolator="true"
    android:fillAfter="true">

    <translate
      android:duration="300"
      android:startOffset="0"
      android:fromXDelta="0"
      android:fromYDelta="0"
      android:toXDelta="100"
      android:toYDelta="100" />

    <scale
      android:duration="300"
      android:startOffset="300"
      android:fromXScale="1.0"
      android:fromYScale="1.0"
      android:toXScale="0.0"
      android:toYScale="0.0" />

  </set>
```

Comment: could u please provide any pragmatic example?

Answer (score 0):

You have taken a Set with one translate animation only. Which wouldn't work.

Try putting both translate animations inside a single Set.

Example snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@anim/cycle" >

    <translate
        android:duration="2500"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="15" />
    <translate
        android:duration="2500"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="100%p" />

</set>
```

You can also give this one  a try:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@anim/cycle" >

    <rotate
        android:duration="2500"
        android:fromDegrees="-5"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatCount="5"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:toDegrees="5" />
    <translate
        android:duration="2500"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="100" 
        android:repeatCount="0"/>

</set>
```

You will need to fix repeatCount and delta as per your requirement.

Hope this helps.